# Is there an efficient way to break long multi-variable polynomials into sums/differences of powers of linear combinations of variables?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

To illustrate what I mean, consider the expression

$$
−A^4 + 4 A^3 B − 4 A^3 D − 6 A^2 B^2 + 12 A^2 B D − 6 A^2 D^2 + 4 A B^3 − 12 A B^2 D + 12 A B D^2 − 4 A D^3
$$

This can be re-written much more compactly as

$$
(B − D)^4 − (A − B + D)^4
$$

I started with the first expression and, through much guesswork and trial-and-error experimentation, found the second expression. I have multiple other, longer expressions that I want to simplify in a similar way, but to do so with the same process feels quite daunting. For example, two of the other expressions are

$$
A^4 − 4 A^3 B + 18 A^2 B^2 − 12 A^2 B G − 12 A^2 B H + 20 A B^3 + 24 A B^2 D − 36 A B^2 G − 36 A B^2 H − 24 A B D G − 24 A B D H + 12 A B G^2 + 24 A B G H + 12 A B H^2 + 12 B^4 + 24 B^3 D − 24 B^3 G − 24 B^3 H + 12 B^2 D^2 − 36 B^2 D G − 36 B^2 D H + 12 B^2 G^2 + 36 B^2 G H + 12 B^2 H^2 − 12 B D^2 G − 12 B D^2 H + 12 B D G^2 + 24 B D G H + 12 B D H^2 − 12 B G^2 H − 12 B G H^2
$$

and

$$
4 A^3 H + 12 A^2 B H + 12 A^2 D H − 12 A^2 G H − 6 A^2 H^2 + 12 A B^2 H − 24 A B G H − 12 A B H^2 + 12 A D^2 H − 24 A D G H − 12 A D H^2 + 12 A G^2 H + 12 A G H^2 + 4 A H^3 + 4 B^3 H + 12 B^2 D H − 12 B^2 G H − 6 B^2 H^2 + 12 B D^2 H − 24 B D G H − 12 B D H^2 + 12 B G^2 H + 12 B G H^2 + 4 B H^3 + 4 D^3 H − 12 D^2 G H − 6 D^2 H^2 + 12 D G^2 H + 12 D G H^2 + 4 D H^3 − 4 G^3 H − 6 G^2 H^2 − 4 G H^3 − H^4
$$

I believe that these expression can be broken up into simple sums-and-or-differences of linear combinations of their variables raised to the fourth power, just like the expression at the start of this question, but I don't know of a good way to approach such long polynomials. Is there an efficient algorithm I can use to do this by hand? If not, is there a website or program that can compute it? At 379 and 405 characters long, respectively, those last expressions are ***way*** over the character limit for WolframAlpha.

Comment: where did you get the polynomials?

Comment: @WillJagy They are portions of a piecewise polynomial equation for displacement over time $d(t)$, constructed as the fifth integral of an equation for snap over time $s(t)$ (an integration path that goes snap → jerk → acceleration → velocity → displacement), where $s(t)$ consists of twelve discontinuous horizontal segments (of degree zero) with values of either -1, 0, or 1, and where each integral after snap is made continuous by choosing the appropriate constant of integration. The variables $A$, $B$, $D$, $G$, and $H$ control the widths of the piecewise segments.

Comment: @WillJagy Whoops, the piecewise equations consist of sixteen segments, not twelve.

Comment: @WillJagy The constant added to the last segment at each integration is $\frac{1}{k!} (−A^k − B^k + (B + A)^k − D^k + (D + A)^k + (D + B)^k − G^k − H^k + (H + G − D − B)^k + (H + G − D − A)^k − (H + G − D)^k + (H + G − B − A)^k − (H + G − B)^k − (H + G − A)^k + (H + G)^k)$, where $k$ is the number of integrations already performed — starting at 0 for $s(t)$ and going up to 4 for $d(t)$. The same behavior seems to hold for the constants of the other segments, if I can just find the linear combinations that go into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplifying expressions, sometimes what to do is "depress" them by a change of variables (or get rid of intermediate terms just like for equations). When it's *multi*-variable expressions, that's when it becomes tricky.

---

**I. First**

$$
X = −A^4 + 4 A^3 B − 4 A^3 D − 6 A^2 B^2 + 12 A^2 B D − 6 A^2 D^2 + 4 A B^3 − 12 A B^2 D + 12 A B D^2 − 4 A D^3
$$

Let $D = B+C$, then,

$$X=-(A + C)^4 + C^4$$

Note that $B$ disappears, so the expression really had only two parameters.

---

**II. Second**

The second and third expressions have five variables $A,B,D,G,H$ and to express them as sums of fourth powers $x_i^4\pm(x_i\pm x_j)^4\pm(x_i\pm x_j\pm x_k)^4\pm(x_i\pm x_j\pm x_k\pm x_l)^4$ would be ***very*** tricky indeed. It was probably just luck the first was such. However, we can still simplify them.

$$\color{blue}Y =
A^4 − 4 A^3 B + 18 A^2 B^2 − 12 A^2 B G − 12 A^2 B H + 20 A B^3 + 24 A B^2 D − 36 A B^2 G − 36 A B^2 H − 24 A B D G − 24 A B D H + 12 A B G^2 + 24 A B G H + 12 A B H^2 + 12 B^4 + 24 B^3 D − 24 B^3 G − 24 B^3 H + 12 B^2 D^2 − 36 B^2 D G − 36 B^2 D H + 12 B^2 G^2 + 36 B^2 G H + 12 B^2 H^2 − 12 B D^2 G − 12 B D^2 H + 12 B D G^2 + 24 B D G H + 12 B D H^2 − 12 B G^2 H − 12 B G H^2
$$

Let,

\begin{align}
D &= \tfrac12(- B + P + Q - R) - A\\ 
G &= \tfrac12(+ B - P + Q - R)\\
H &= \tfrac12(+ B + P - Q - R)
\end{align}

then we get the much simpler,

$$\color{blue}Y = (A - B)^4 - B^4 + 12 B P Q R$$

If $PQR=0$, then it is a difference of two fourth powers, like the first.

---

**III. Third**

The has a simplified form analogous to the second.

$$
\color{red}Z = 4 A^3 H + 12 A^2 B H + 12 A^2 D H − 12 A^2 G H − 6 A^2 H^2 + 12 A B^2 H − 24 A B G H − 12 A B H^2 + 12 A D^2 H − 24 A D G H − 12 A D H^2 + 12 A G^2 H + 12 A G H^2 + 4 A H^3 + 4 B^3 H + 12 B^2 D H − 12 B^2 G H − 6 B^2 H^2 + 12 B D^2 H − 24 B D G H − 12 B D H^2 + 12 B G^2 H + 12 B G H^2 + 4 B H^3 + 4 D^3 H − 12 D^2 G H − 6 D^2 H^2 + 12 D G^2 H + 12 D G H^2 + 4 D H^3 − 4 G^3 H − 6 G^2 H^2 − 4 G H^3 − H^4
$$

Let $G = A + B + D + J$, then it is just,

$$\color{red}Z = -(H+J)^4 +J^4 -24 A B D H $$

or explicitly,

$$\color{red}Z = -(A + B + D -G - H)^4 + (A + B + D -G)^4 -24 A B D H $$

If $ABD=0$, then it is also a difference of two fourth powers, like the first two.