# Is there an efficient algorithm/procedure to perform this type of simplification?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

Consider the expression

$$2 A^3+3 A^2 B-4 A^2 E-2 A^2 F-A^2 G+A B^2-4 A B E-2 A B F-A B G+2 E^3+3 E^2 F+E^2 G+E F^2+E F G \\
\text{[95 characters]}$$

It cannot be factored directly, but it can be re-written as

$$A (A+B) (2 A+B-(4 E+2 F+G))+E (E+F) (2 E+F+G) \\
\text{[43 characters, or a 54.74% reduction]}$$

by breaking it into two groups of terms which ***can*** be factored. With this example case, the grouping-and-factoring is simple and straightforward. However, the process I use becomes rapidly more difficult and time-consuming as the length of the starting expression increases.

**Is there an efficient way to find such groupings for expressions of similar structure but much greater length?** Specifically, I'd like to get the shortest possible representation of a given expression, counting all operands (including multiplication signs, implied or explicit), operators, coefficients, and brackets.

My end-goal is to simplify things like this monstrosity as much as possible:

$$
137/2 A^5+685/4 A^4 B+925/6 A^3 B^2+60 A^2 B^3+103/12 A B^4+64 A^4 C+128 A^3 B C+80 A^2 B^2 C+16 A B^3 C+20 A^3 C^2+30 A^2 B C^2+10 A B^2 C^2+2 A^2 C^3+2 A B C^3+28 A^4 D+56 A^3 B D+35 A^2 B^2 D+7 A B^3 D+18 A^3 C D+27 A^2 B C D+9 A B^2 C D+3 A^2 C^2 D+3 A B C^2 D+3 A^3 D^2+9/2 A^2 B D^2+3/2 A B^2 D^2+A^2 C D^2+A B C D^2-55/3 A^4 E-110/3 A^3 B E-23 A^2 B^2 E-14/3 A B^3 E-16 A^3 C E-24 A^2 B C E-8 A B^2 C E-4 A^2 C^2 E-4 A B C^2 E-12 A^3 D E-18 A^2 B D E-6 A B^2 D E-4 A^2 C D E-4 A B C D E-2 A^2 D^2 E-2 A B D^2 E-40 A^3 E^2-60 A^2 B E^2-20 A B^2 E^2-16 A^2 C E^2-16 A B C E^2-8 A^2 D E^2-8 A B D E^2+76/3 A^2 E^3+76/3 A B E^3+9 B^2 E^3+24 A C E^3+12 B C E^3+4 C^2 E^3+12 A D E^3+6 B D E^3+4 C D E^3+D^2 E^3+24 A E^4+12 B E^4+8 C E^4+4 D E^4+9/2 E^5-55/6 A^4 F-55/3 A^3 B F-23/2 A^2 B^2 F-7/3 A B^3 F-8 A^3 C F-12 A^2 B C F-4 A B^2 C F-2 A^2 C^2 F-2 A B C^2 F-6 A^3 D F-9 A^2 B D F-3 A B^2 D F-2 A^2 C D F-2 A B C D F-A^2 D^2 F-A B D^2 F-40 A^3 E F-60 A^2 B E F-20 A B^2 E F-16 A^2 C E F-16 A B C E F-8 A^2 D E F-8 A B D E F+38 A^2 E^2 F+38 A B E^2 F+27/2 B^2 E^2 F+36 A C E^2 F+18 B C E^2 F+6 C^2 E^2 F+18 A D E^2 F+9 B D E^2 F+6 C D E^2 F+3/2 D^2 E^2 F+48 A E^3 F+24 B E^3 F+16 C E^3 F+8 D E^3 F+45/4 E^4 F-10 A^3 F^2-15 A^2 B F^2-5 A B^2 F^2-4 A^2 C F^2-4 A B C F^2-2 A^2 D F^2-2 A B D F^2+10 A^2 E F^2+10 A B E F^2+9/2 B^2 E F^2+12 A C E F^2+6 B C E F^2+2 C^2 E F^2+6 A D E F^2+3 B D E F^2+2 C D E F^2+1/2 D^2 E F^2+30 A E^2 F^2+15 B E^2 F^2+10 C E^2 F^2+5 D E^2 F^2+61/6 E^3 F^2-4/3 A^2 F^3-4/3 A B F^3+6 A E F^3+3 B E F^3+2 C E F^3+D E F^3+4 E^2 F^3+7/12 E F^4-55/12 A^4 G-55/6 A^3 B G-23/4 A^2 B^2 G-7/6 A B^3 G-4 A^3 C G-6 A^2 B C G-2 A B^2 C G-A^2 C^2 G-A B C^2 G-3 A^3 D G-9/2 A^2 B D G-3/2 A B^2 D G-A^2 C D G-A B C D G-1/2 A^2 D^2 G-1/2 A B D^2 G-20 A^3 E G-30 A^2 B E G-10 A B^2 E G-8 A^2 C E G-8 A B C E G-4 A^2 D E G-4 A B D E G+10 A^2 E^2 G+10 A B E^2 G+9/2 B^2 E^2 G+12 A C E^2 G+6 B C E^2 G+2 C^2 E^2 G+6 A D E^2 G+3 B D E^2 G+2 C D E^2 G+1/2 D^2 E^2 G+18 A E^3 G+9 B E^3 G+6 C E^3 G+3 D E^3 G+55/12 E^4 G-10 A^3 F G-15 A^2 B F G-5 A B^2 F G-4 A^2 C F G-4 A B C F G-2 A^2 D F G-2 A B D F G+10 A^2 E F G+10 A B E F G+9/2 B^2 E F G+12 A C E F G+6 B C E F G+2 C^2 E F G+6 A D E F G+3 B D E F G+2 C D E F G+1/2 D^2 E F G+27 A E^2 F G+27/2 B E^2 F G+9 C E^2 F G+9/2 D E^2 F G+55/6 E^3 F G-2 A^2 F^2 G-2 A B F^2 G+9 A E F^2 G+9/2 B E F^2 G+3 C E F^2 G+3/2 D E F^2 G+23/4 E^2 F^2 G+7/6 E F^3 G-5/2 A^3 G^2-15/4 A^2 B G^2-5/4 A B^2 G^2-A^2 C G^2-A B C G^2-1/2 A^2 D G^2-1/2 A B D G^2-2 A^2 E G^2-2 A B E G^2+3 A E^2 G^2+3/2 B E^2 G^2+C E^2 G^2+1/2 D E^2 G^2+3/2 E^3 G^2-A^2 F G^2-A B F G^2+3 A E F G^2+3/2 B E F G^2+C E F G^2+1/2 D E F G^2+9/4 E^2 F G^2+3/4 E F^2 G^2-1/6 A^2 G^3-1/6 A B G^3+1/6 E^2 G^3+1/6 E F G^3 \\
\text{[2729 characters]}
$$

## Background for the Monstrous Expression

We have the following function:

```
f(n) = (
   (12*A + 6*B + 4*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - (11*A + 6*B + 4*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - (11*A + 5*B + 4*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + (10*A + 5*B + 4*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - (10*A + 5*B + 3*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + ( 9*A + 5*B + 3*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + ( 9*A + 4*B + 3*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - ( 8*A + 4*B + 3*C + 2*D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - ( 8*A + 4*B + 3*C +   D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + ( 7*A + 4*B + 3*C +   D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + ( 7*A + 3*B + 3*C +   D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 3*C +   D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D + 4*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D + 3*E + 2*F + G)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D + 3*E +   F + G)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D + 2*E +   F + G)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D + 2*E +   F)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D +   E +   F)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D +   E)^n
 - ( 6*A + 3*B + 2*C +   D)^n
 + ( 6*A + 3*B +   C +   D)^n
 - ( 5*A + 3*B +   C +   D)^n
 - ( 5*A + 2*B +   C +   D)^n
 + ( 4*A + 2*B +   C +   D)^n
 + ( 4*A + 2*B +   C)^n
 - ( 3*A + 2*B +   C)^n
 - ( 3*A +   B +   C)^n
 + ( 2*A +   B +   C)^n
 - ( 2*A +   B)^n
 + (   A +   B)^n
 +     A^n
)/(n!)
```

It is not difficult to check that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = f(2) = 0$. The first example expression I give is the expanded form of $f(3)$. The expanded-and-simplified form of $f(4)$ is:

$$(A (A+B) (2 A+B-(4 E+2 F+G))+E (E+F) (2 E+F+G)) (12 A+6 B+4 C+2 D+4 E+2 F+G)/2$$

Note that the first parenthetical portion of $f(4)$ is just $f(3)$ again. Also note that each parenthetical in $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ consists of a portion of one of the exponentiated terms in $f(n)$; I don't know how significant that is, but it feels worth pointing out.

The monstrous expression is the expanded form of $f(5)$.

The lower-level variables $A$ through $E$ have values that are (in theory) combinations of a set of six top-level variables whose values are (somewhat-)arbitrary non-negative real numbers:

- $d_{max}$
- $v_{limit}$
- $a_{limit}$
- $j_{limit}$
- $s_{limit}$
- $c_{max}$

Four of the lower-level variables have known values:

- $A = \frac{s_{limit}}{c_{max}}$
- $B = \frac{j_{limit}}{s_{limit}} - \frac{s_{limit}}{c_{max}}$
- $C = \frac{a_{limit}}{j_{limit}} - \frac{j_{limit}}{s_{limit}} - \frac{s_{limit}}{c_{max}}$
- $D = \frac{v_{limit}}{a_{limit}} - \frac{a_{limit}}{j_{limit}} - \frac{j_{limit}}{s_{limit}} - \frac{s_{limit}}{c_{max}}$

I also know that $f(3) = f(4) = 0$ and $f(5) = d_{max}$.

I eventually want to solve for $E$, $F$, and $G$, but I need to figure out an additional known value somewhere to have a fully-determined system of equations.

Comment: When looking at expressions even very much longer than this in my own work, I find it usually helps to review the processes that generated it. What's the source of the expression? What is it supposed to capture?

Comment: @Blue The very long expression ultimately gives the total distance traveled by an object whose motion is given by continuous piecewise polynomial functions for displacement, velocity, acceleration, jerk, and snap, and a discontinuous piecewise polynomial function for crack, plus constrains on the maximum allowed velocity, acceleration, jerk, snap, and crack. The constraints are contained in the variables A through G. I know the values of A through D, and I eventually want to solve for E, F, and G using the family of equations that includes the very long expression in my question.

Comment: In playing with this a bit, I'm seeing (as in your sample expressions) factors $a(a+b)(2a+b)$ and $c(c+d)(2c+d)$. Is there *symmetry* in these values? That is, is there reason to believe that $a$ and $b$ should "act like" $c$ and $d$? Does some pair of $e$, $f$, $g$ *also* act like them, with the third being an oddity; or is there a separate $e$-$f$-$g$ symmetry? Are there other connections? Giving specific definitions of each variable would help with this stuff. (Be sure to put all clarifications into the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue I added clarification to the question body. As part of that update, I changed some of the variables in the first example so everything matches up properly.

Comment: Have you tried CAS such as Wolfram Mathematica? This may be a better question for https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Somos I can't afford Mathematica, and the main expression I'm concerned with is far too long to fit within WolframAlpha's 200-character limit.

Comment: Okay, then try [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) instead.

Comment: @Somos I tried Wolfram Engine, and neither `Simplify[]` nor `FullSimplify[]` completely simplify $f(3)$, $f(4)$ or $f(5)$. It makes an OK attempt at $f(3)$, but $f(5)$ sees almost no improvement.

Comment: Your eventual goal is not to simplify expressions but to solve equations. Wolfram Engine can solve some equations. Try that instead.

Comment: @Somos I don't have a fully determined system of equations yet; I have three unknown variables ($E$, $F$, & $G$), but only two equations ($f(3)$ and $f(5)$; I can't use $f(4)$ because $f(3)$ is a factor of $f(4)$ and is equal to zero, so the other factor-term in $f(4)$ gives no additional information). So solving will have to wait. What I'm currently interested in is the topic of this question: simplifying very long expressions.

Comment: @Lawton: It happens that $f(2n)$ always has a factor of $12A+6B+4C+2D+4E+2F+G$, which suggests to me that there's some structure here that might be exploited —perhaps a recursion— but I haven't seen how. Anyway, from what I can tell, you're not doing yourself any favors with your definitions of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. I get some slightly-more-manageable expressions by keeping things in terms of the component fractions $s_{limit}/c_{max}$, etc. (Eg, that factor is "simply" $2(a/j+v/a)+4E+2F+G$.) Are your $E$, $F$, $G$ also combinations of other values? This may improve things even more.

Comment: @Blue In theory, $E$, $F$, and $G$ should be combinations of the same variables as $A$ through $D$, but their exact values are currently unknown to me. As I say at the end of the question, I eventually want to solve for them once I figure out a completely determined system of equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really have an algorithm or procedure to recommend except "persistence". :)

I played around with the expression quite a bit (checking my work in *Mathematica*), and I kept running into seemingly-natural groupings $A(A+B)$ and $E(E+F)(2E+F+G)$; but the overall expression remained a mess. Looking back at the question, I realized OP's definitions of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ were making things a bit more complicated than they need to be; substituting back the component ratios made things a bit simpler. To save typing here, I'll abbreviate those ratios as $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, such that
$$A = a \qquad B = b - a \qquad C = c - a - b \qquad D = d - a - b - c
\quad\to\quad A(A+B)=ab$$
OP didn't say so, but I'll make comparable definitions of $E$, $F$, $G$, as these simplify that other grouping:
$$E=e \qquad F = f-e \qquad G = g-e-f \quad\to\quad E(E+F)(2E+F+G) = efg$$
Further, define
$$p := e+f+g \qquad q := p-a-b$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
f(3) &= efg - abq \\[6pt]
2\,f(4) &= \left(p+2(c+d) \right)\,f(3) \\[6pt]
12\,f(5) &= 2 \left(p^2+3p(c+d)+3 (c+d)^2\right)\,f(3) \\[4pt]
&\quad-e^2f^2g^2\,\left(\frac1e+\frac1f+\frac1g\right) \\[4pt] 
&\quad+ ab\,\left(\; (a+b)q^2 + abq + 12 cd\,(q+c+d) \;\right)
\end{align}$$
A considerable improvement over the original form, I believe. :)

---

Here's one way of getting to the result. It's not exactly an "efficient algorithm/procedure" in the sense of an automatable process; it's more of a process that's driven by my own observations and hunches about patterns and groupings.

Making the substitutions
$$A \to a \qquad B \to b-a \qquad C\to c-(a+b) \qquad D\to d-(a+b+c)$$
$$E \to e \qquad F \to f - e \qquad G\to g-(e+f)$$

the monster expansion for $12\,f(5)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\phantom{+}a^4 b + 2 a^3 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^3 + a b^4 + 6 a^2 b c^2 + 6 a b^2 c^2 + 12 a b c^2 d \\
&+ 6 a^2 b d^2 + 6 a b^2 d^2 + 12 a b c d^2 \\
&\color{red}{-2 a^3 b e - 3 a^2 b^2 e - 2 a b^3 e+ 6 a^2 b c e + 6 a b^2 c e - 6 a b c^2 e + 6 a^2 b d e + 6 a b^2 d e - 6 a b d^2 e} \\
&\color{blue}{+ 3 a^2 b e^2 + 3 a b^2 e^2 - 6 a b c e^2 - 6 a b d e^2} \\
&\color{purple}{- 2 a b e^3} \\
&\color{red}{- 2 a^3 b f - 3 a^2 b^2 f- 2 a b^3 f + 6 a^2 b c f + 6 a b^2 c f - 6 a b c^2 f + 6 a^2 b d f + 6 a b^2 d f- 6 a b d^2 f} \\
&\color{darkgreen}{+ 6 a^2 b e f + 6 a b^2 e f - 12 a b c e f - 12 a b d e f} \\
&\color{purple}{ - 6 a b e^2 f} \\
&\color{blue}{+ 3 a^2 b f^2 + 3 a b^2 f^2 - 6 a b c f^2 - 
 6 a b d f^2}\\
&\color{purple}{- 6 a b e f^2 - 2 a b f^3} \\
&\color{red}{- 2 a^3 b g - 3 a^2 b^2 g - 2 a b^3 g + 6 a^2 b c g + 6 a b^2 c g - 6 a b c^2 g + 6 a^2 b d g+ 6 a b^2 d g - 6 a b d^2 g}\\
&\color{darkgreen}{+ 6 a^2 b e g + 6 a b^2 e g - 12 a b c e g - 12 a b d e g} \\
&\color{purple}{- 6 a b e^2 g} \\
&\color{darkgreen}{+ 6 a^2 b f g + 6 a b^2 f g - 12 a b c f g - 12 a b d f g} \\
&\color{purple}{- 12 a b e f g} \\
&+ 6 c^2 e f g + 12 c d e f g + 6 d^2 e f g \\
&+ 6 c e^2 f g + 6 d e^2 f g \\
&+ 2 e^3 f g \\
&\color{purple}{- 6 a b f^2 g} \\
& + 6 c e f^2 g + 6 d e f^2 g \\
&+ 3 e^2 f^2 g + 2 e f^3 g \\
&\color{blue}{+ 3 a^2 b g^2 + 3 a b^2 g^2 - 6 a b c g^2 - 
 6 a b d g^2 }\\
&\color{purple}{- 6 a b e g^2 - 6 a b f g^2}\\
&+ 6 c e f g^2 + 6 d e f g^2 \\
&+ 3 e^2 f g^2 + 3 e f^2 g^2 \\
&\color{purple}{- 2 a b g^3} \\
&+ 2 e f g^3
\end{align}$$

Still a monster, but something interesting has happened. The coefficients are simply $1$, $2$, $3$, $6$, $12$ instead of the cacophony of values in the original form. This suggests that monster *likes* the substitutions.

The coefficient pairs $(1,2)$, $(3,6)$, $(6,3)$ suggest that I might want to be looking for squares $(x+y)^2$ or $(x+y+z)^2$; also $(1,3)$, $(2,6)$, $(1,3,6)$ and $(2,6,12)$ suggest looking for cubes $(x+y)^3$ or $(x+y+z)^3$. Sometimes these groupings jump out at me sometimes not. I won't look too hard right now.

Often, I typically start playing with monsters by introducing line breaks as I go along, and seeing if I detect any similar groupings. Here, I find a lot of them. That's why the expression above is so ragged. And I color-coded lines that seem suspiciously similar.

- The red lines differ in a factor of $e$, $f$, or $g$; together, we can factor-out $(e+f+g)$.
- Likewise, the blues allow us to factor-out $(e^2+f^2+g^2)$; the greens, $2(ef+fg+ge)$. Hey, that's $(e+f+g)^2$!
- Also, the purples together give us a factor of $(e+f+g)^3$!
- Other lines indicate a factor of $(a+b)$, $(c+d)$, $(c+d)^2$, or $efg$.

Let's define $p:=e+f+g$ to reduce a bit of clutter. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\phantom{+}ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2) \\
&+ 6 a b (a+b) (c^2+d^2) \\
&+ 12 a b c d (c+d) \\
&+ab\left(-2 a^2 - 3 a b- 2 b^2+ 6 a c + 6 b c  + 6 a d + 6 b d - 6 c^2 - 6 d^2\right)p \\
&+3ab\left(a + b - 2c - 2 d\right)p^2 \\
&- 2 a b p^3 \\
&+ 6 (c+d)^2 e f g \\
&+ 6 (c+d)\,e f g p \\
&+ 2 e f g (e^2+f^2+g^2) \\
&+ 3 e f g (ef+fg+ge)
\end{align}$$

Looking better already. (We can now see that the expression is also symmetric in $a$ and $b$, as well as $c$ and $d$. Good to know!)

There are a few quadratic groupings that are *close* to perfect squares. Let's take a chance and re-write them as
$$a^2+ab+b^2=(a+b)^2-ab \qquad 2a^2+3ab+2b^2=2(a+b)^2-ab$$
$$c^2+d^2=(c+d)^2-2cd$$
$$2(e^2+f^2+g^2)+3(ef+fg+ge)=2p^2-(ef+fg+ge)$$

Let's also define $u:=a+b$ and $v:=c+d$ to tighten things up a bit. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\phantom{+}abu(u^2-ab) \tag{1.1}\\
&+ 6 a b u (v^2-2cd) \tag{1.2}\\
&+ 12 a b c d v \tag{1.3}\\
&+ab\left(-2u^2+ab + 6uv - 6v^2 +12cd\right)p \tag{1.4}\\
&+3ab\left(u - 2v\right)p^2 \tag{1.5}\\
&- 2 a b p^3 \tag{1.6}\\
&+ 2 e f g (p^2+3pv+3v^2) \tag{1.7}\\
&- e f g (ef+fg+ge) \tag{1.8}
\end{align}$$

Line $(1.7)$ comes from gathering stray $efg$ terms together. Observe that we can construct other occurrences of its factor $p^2+3pv+3v^2$ in lines $(1.6)$, $(1.5)$, $(1.4)$, and lines $(1.5)$, $(1.4)$, $(1.2)$.

$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\phantom{+}abu(u^2-ab) \tag{2.1}\\
&- 12 a b c d u \tag{2.2}\\
&+ 12 a b c d v \tag{2.3}\\
&+ab\left(-2u^2+ab +12cd\right)p \tag{2.4}\\
&+abup^2 \tag{2.5}\\
&+2abu\left(p^2+3pv+3v^2\right) \tag{2.6}\\
&- 2 a b p \left(p^2+3pv+3v^2\right) \tag{2.7}\\
&+ 2 e f g (p^2+3pv+3v^2) \tag{2.8}\\
&- e f g (ef+fg+ge) \tag{2.9}
\end{align}$$

From here, we can perhaps see how other groupings involving $p-u$  reveal themselves.

$$\begin{align}
&\;\;\phantom{+}a^2b^2(p-u) \tag{3.1}\\
&+ 12 a b c d (p-u+v) \tag{3.2}\\
&+abu(p-u)^2 \tag{3.3}\\
&- 2 a b (p-u) \left(p^2+3pv+3v^2\right) \tag{3.4}\\
&+ 2 e f g (p^2+3pv+3v^2) \tag{3.5}\\
&- e f g (ef+fg+ge) \tag{3.6}
\end{align}$$

A little rearranging, and defining $q:=p-u$, gives the form I provided above. Maybe there's a faster path to it, but this is more-or-less how I got there.

---

By the way, it's *intriguing* that
$$p^2+3p(c+d)+3(c+d)^2$$
could be written as $$\frac1p\left((p+c+d)^3-(c+d)^3\right)$$
but that doesn't seem to help.

---

The same kind of playing with, and observing patterns in, OP's original expression is what made me realize that OP's $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ were making things unnecessarily difficult compared to just using $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$; and likewise that $E$, $F$, $G$ "wanted" to be expressed in the $e$, $f$, $g$ forms I gave.

If there's an automatable process in all of this, I don't know what it is. I personally find the manual pattern-finding pretty satisfying. :)

(I'll note that my "manual" process involves numerous assists from *Mathematica* to check factorization hunches as well as to ensure that I haven't made sign errors or other typos as I've gone along.)

Comment: Can you explain at all the procedure you used to simplify $f(5)$ after making the substitutions for your newly-defined variables?

Comment: @Lawton: That'll take some time to write up. I'll try to get to it this weekend.

Comment: @Blue Here's [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4723991/4781) from the OP about simplifying expressions, which I found involved a difference two $4$th powers.  I agree the "manual pattern-finding" (assisted by Mathematica) is satisfying indeed. However, I can foresee in the future we will be replaced by a Jarvis-like AI that will be infinitely faster at pattern recognition. Sigh.